# How do I change the active nav li in separate header.html when on different pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, header-files

I have a site with 6 pages where the header is in a separate file. I would like the nav links to be highlighted as active depending on which page I am on.

This is the main nav from the header.html:

```
<div id="fh5co-main-nav">
    <nav id="fh5co-nav" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.html">Location</a> </li>
            <li><a href="cafe.html">Cafe</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

It is linked in each page with this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

In my main.js I have this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
  });
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get current URL path and assign 'active' class
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $('ul.nav li > a[href="/'+pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

...but I cannot seem to figure out why it is not working. Any advice anyone could give would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchors are relative paths i.e. `href="contact.html"` so the selector `[href="/'+pathname+'"]` you're using won't match any of them unless you change the value of your anchors to contain a preceding slash.

`$.load` accepts a callback function which allows you to execute logic after the resource is loaded inserted into the DOM.

`this` inside the callback is set to the DOM element which the `load` method was applied to i.e. `#header`.

`window.location.pathname` will always include the initial `'/'` so there is no need to prefix this in the selector.

I've also thrown in some logic to toggle active states on sibling elements.

```
$(function(){
  $('#header').load('header.html', function () {
    $('.nav a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]', this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }); 
  $('#footer').load('footer.html'); 
});
```